# Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend had hosted a Minecraft server before and brought it back up today with my help. He and anyone in his LAN can connect. However we have had a few people try to connect, including me, and when we try to connect it gives the message:

> Failed to connect to the server
>
> Connection timed out: connect

What does this exactly mean? How do we fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be multiple reasons. But basically your game asked to be connected and never received a response.

Usually you want to check :

- Firewall settings
- Router/modem settings (port redirection)
- IP config of the minecraft server (he should listen from the IP of your PC or 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1)
- Check you specify the right port in the connection box
- That you use the correct IP address or server name (and that he does resolve correctly)
- That your server has a working internet connection as well

Comment: the only thing i understand there is the firewall settigns wich i already let minecraft through but i dont know how 2 do the rest.:( little help youtube videos or anything?

Comment: @super We can't really give Networking 101 lessons here. Google is a good first stop for learning what IP addresses are and how servers and clients use them.