# timing out when trying to connect to my own server using Hamachi

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Recently I've been unable to connect to my Minecraft server which I play on with a friend. It seems my friend has been able to access it just fine, but every time I try to connect I get the error:

> connection lost: timed out

The strange thing is, this happened seemingly out of nowhere while I was playing two days ago. I lost my connection to the server while I was playing, and then when I tried to reconnect, I got this error. I've looked all over the internet for a solution, but I've tried everything that was suggested: my firewall is completely turned off, and I have set both inbound and outbound rules for hamachi. Resetting the server doesn't seem to help, nor does restarting my machine. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

I've seen a somewhat similar problem raised in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server), but all of its answers either don't work for me, or are not applicable because I'm using Hamachi instead of port forwarding. My firewall settings have not changed since I was previously able to connect--same for my router/modem settings. IPconfig is not applicable because I'm using the IP address given to me by Hamachi, not the IP address of my machine. I didn't specify a port when I was initially able to connect. Additionally, the IP address of the Hamachi network I'm using hasn't changed since I was able to connect. And I can confirm that I do indeed have a working internet connection. Therefore I conclude that my problem is an entirely separate one from the one raise in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server).

Comment: If there is a problem with the question to warrant a downvote, it would be helpful if you told me what the issue is so that I may correct it.

Comment: @Rapitor I saw that question, but I decided to ask it as a separate question because the answers given either didn't work for me, or weren't applicable because I'm not using port forwarding (I'm using Hamachi instead). So I figure it's safe to assume that this is a different issue from the one in the other question.

Comment: Really? It got closed despite the fact that I proved in the comments that this question isn't a duplicate? In the future, it would probably be helpful to read the comments before voting to close.

Comment: Once the closing process starts it's difficult to stop it... I have however voted to reopen.

Comment: Hamachi still requires port forwarding, to my knowledge.  I'm not sure how it's not the same problem; just adding in Hamachi doesn't automatically make this a brand new problem.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't require any port forwarding. At least, I've never had to do it before when using Hamachi. [This](http://forum.ragezone.com/f651/portforward-im-using-hamachi-744159/) in addition to several other sources, seem to agree. Can you direct me to where you're getting your information that it requires port forwarding?

Comment: Logic seems to dictate that network applications such as Hamachi require setup to get working properly; there's no way (that I know of, anyways) that Hamachi can do what it's supposed to (which is create a LAN-esque network with other computers), without setting it up within your network.  It might be able to do it's job using the generic ports, but it won't work very well, I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

How are you connecting? Internally or externally (are you getting your ip from the ipconfig command in the command prompt or from a website). If you're not, try connecting internally. Also, I'd really learn how to port forward (there are thousands of tutorials for Minecraft port forwarding everywhere) as Hamachi lets viruses in everywhere and can really mess up an internet connection. Also, keep your firewall on!

Comment: I'm using the IP that Hamachi gives me.

Comment: @Ataraxia There is no reason to use that IP instead of `localhost`. The server is running on your Computer, not on Hamachi. Hamachi only allows external people to easily connect to your computer via VPN. Leave `server-ip` blank in `server.properties`. It should be joinable via *any* applicable IP. If you think of IPs as a name or rather nicknames of your comp that are used in certain circles, `localhost` corresponds to you calling yourself "I", while your Hamachi IP corresponds to whatever your friends call you.

Comment: @MrLemon When I was using my own IP, my friend was unable to connect to my server. Also, I'm not sure that using Hamachi instead of the localhost is the problem, since I was able to connect before despite the fact that I was using the Hamachi IP.