# "Timed Out" error when trying to join server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can join the server and sometimes the map would load for the server but i would just fall through the map and it would dissconect me and say timed out, any solutions?

Comment: Downvoters and closers, this really happens very often so please don't close it as there may not be any more explanations.

Comment: Is this only for one specific server or for all server you try to join?

Comment: Normally, We'd need more information on this question to be able to give an actual answer. There are literally thousands of suggestions on the cause and fix for this behavior from minecraft. Given the time since the quesiton has been asked, I've vote to close as it's a poor question.

Comment: Does the error include the message "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException"? Questions keep being suggested as duplicates as this one, but they only have the 'Timed out' message in common. Apart from that, this question seems rather low quality.

Comment: @Joachim (and everyone else) woudln't [this older question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server) be the correct target to dupe "connection timed out" to instead?

Comment: You're unlikely to get a response to that question, as the asker is an unregistered user and hasn't been seen for 3 years

Comment: @pppery This question you mean, right? I think the post you linked is indeed already a better candidate, but - again - it would be good if a mod could merge the separate threads.

Comment: @Joachim This question, and all of the questions people are VTCing as duplicate to it. OK, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your WiFi is probably lagging. Try restarting your WiFi adapter. To restart your WiFi adapter:

1. Right click your wifi icon in the bottom right corner.
2. Open network and sharing center.
3. Click your router name in the top right corner.
4. Click disable.
5. Click enable.

Comment: After i clicled disabke, where do i go to press enable?

Comment: @NeoGamezHD What Windows or Mac version do you have?

Comment: Or the server is lagging horbily. Or he just loves to far away form the server host

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having this happen is ultimately because:

## Your client is not receiving any world data from the server, and the server has stopped responding to its requests for the world.

This can be caused by several things, such as:

- The server is slow to process and to send you the world data (Get a better server).
- Your internet is slow to receive the data from the server (Get a better internet connection, or free up your bandwidth; stop downloading other things).
- Your server's internet connection is slow to upload the world (Get a better internet connection for the server).
- Your computer is slow to process the world (Get a better computer, but Minecraft should've *already* crashed or hung before even reaching this point and is definitely not the case if you're getting at least 1 frame per second).