# Lan server on Minecraft not working Pls help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Me and my brother are trying to do a LAN world together but it always says io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out. What does that mean?? I am on an iMac and he is on a windows ten dell laptop. We also have mods, but have downloaded the same ones. We are on the same wifi network, but have different final numbers in the Ip address. What is going  on? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because troubleshooting Minecraft with mods installed is off-topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Answer (score 1):

Follow each one of these steps and then try again.

1. If you are using the same minecraft account, You cannot play together. Purchace minecraft a second time.
2. Are you on the same version?
3. (On the windows laptop) Make sure minecraft is allowed in your firewall. You can see more about that in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn2BJ9jLYNs)
4. On the iMac: Make sure minecraft is allowed in your firewall.

   1. Open System Preferences.
   2. Click the Security or Security & Privacy icon.
   3. Select the Firewall tab.
   4. Click the lock icon in the preference pane, then enter an administrator name 
      and password.
   5. Click the Firewall Options button
   6. Click the Add Application (+) button.
   7. Select the app you want to allow incoming connection privileges for.
   8. Click Add.
   9. Click OK.

Hope this helps!! :)

Answer (score 0):

As Blurz Ice stated out, you should make sure that Minecraft is allowed in your firewall.
If that still doesn't work I would recommend setting up a Minecraft server.
Here are the instructions for Windows. I have no experience of iMac, so in case the server is on the iMac, google is your friend.

1. Download the Minecraft server jar either through your launcher or from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/fi-fi/download/server) and save it to an empty folder.
2. Open notepad and paste the following text into it, replacing the 1.12.2 with the corresponding version you are using:
   `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar nogui && pause`
3. Save the file as a .bat file. See the image below:[image]
4. Double click the .bat file
   You should see a window pop up. It is the server. Enter`stop` to stop the server when you want to stop playing.

**EDIT**

I didn't clarify this enough.
You should also have [java](https://java.com/en/download/) installed. If it's still not working (not even creating a file with the name eula.txt. In case there IS eula.txt, make sure you have read the End User Licence Agreement of Minecraft server and edit the file in Notepad so that the row `eula=false` would be `eula=true`) you should get the %PATH% variable working next. There are a bunch of tutorials on doing it, so the first thing I would search for is: "Add java to %PATH% on Windows 10"

Comment: Sorry to annoy you, but when I click on the file, the command terminal flashes on-screen for about a milli-second and then it closes. (I am using the windows ten)

Comment: I think thats normal. The terminal flashes on screen beacuse it is doing a "command" for the game. It should open up.

Comment: @VenToastGaming Do you have java installed? If not, please download java from the [website](https://java.com/en/download/).