# Minecraft 1.5.2 Single Player Open to LAN ends for friend in Timeout

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing minecraft 1.15.2 single player and want to invite some people to play with me there. However every time they try to connect, they get as far as joining and seeing only the sky or an empty minecraft world.

I have setup a hamachi network and for the duration of this I have disabled the firewall of my Antivirus (Eset) which allowed us to get to this point. I even get the chat message that he had joined the game but then after a short while he gets the message that he has timed out.

I have no idea what else to try since we have tried to find a solution for this for quite some time now. I don't know if there is anything better I should try or not or if I have to change something on my side or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: not sure @pppery will try but there aren't many settings to be changed in the singleplayer open in lan world. The only thing I could try was that I put in the IP of my PC instead of the IP that is shown in Hamachi