# Minecraft Lan connection connection error: io.netty.channel.connecttimeoutexception connection timed out on Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, windows

Me and my friend want to play Minecraft together on the same WiFi. He has a Windows 10 computer and I have a Mac. At first, opening to LAN would not show up at all. Then I found a way to prefer IPv4 using:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher
```

This would make my friends place show up on my screen, but my friend would not see my place when we enabled our open to LAN at separate times. I tried disabling my firewall and it would still not work. When I try to connect to my friends place, I get the error

> io.netty.channel.connecttimeoutexception connection timed out.

When my friend tried to direct connect, he would get the same error. Any help is appreciated.
We are both on the same Internet right next to each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: No it does not. We are on 2 different types of computers and I don't really know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I solved this by myself by allowing firewall through his computer. Thanks for all your help

> I went to my friends firewall settings, went to allow app through firewall, and I checked boxes that had the word minecraft or java in it. I found like 2-3 boxes

(from OP in comment)