# Why did I always disconnect from Minecraft Server although my Internet is in good condition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

Here are the issues:

I continuously get disconnected from the Minecraft server although my Internet is in good condition. I use a laptop and not using an adapter such as ethernet, Pardon me if I'm wrong! Well, the issues are I don't use any modem or router, and more likely to use mobile hotspot.

So, the issues that I stress are the problem with connect to the variety server. When I tried to enter the private server that my partner made; I always have an issue where the server will kick me out. The server that I join always sent me messages such as ' connection timed out ', ' can't connect to the server ', or ' connection lost ' [ Something like that ]. And when I tried to join another server, the connection just smooth and really well!

Back to my partner server, his friends can join it placidly and doesn't have any problems regarding the issues that stated ' Connection Timed Out ', ETC.

So the thing that I've tried before is to flush the DNS, changes the port, rebooting the devices, turn off the hotspot and then turn it on repeatedly, modify the name of hotspot and password, turn off the firewall, update the drivers, change the DNS addresses and other that I have researched to get this issue fixed.

but sadly turn out the progress or culmination is still same and I still can't connect to the server considerably.

More is that the ping is regularly high when I joined the server but when I tried to join another server, the ping just becomes lower and lower and the experienced become more smooths. Also, the server that I wanted to join didn't have any problems and **my partner friends can join it smoothly without any problems that I've faced.**

In fact, I don't have any anti-virus software and only using the original that built inside my laptop. I'm using Window 10 Pro and using brand named ASUS with AMD4 A4 type. I've already tried using the command prompt as I already stated in the second paragraph and I already changed the hotspot AP band into 5Ghz Band. Furthermore, my internet around here is really well and smooths and I even can download 5GB software within 50 minutes or more without any problems and I can even watch YouTube or listens to the music or Video Call with my partner during the download period.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: Nope, sorry. All of those things I already tried as I stated in the second paragraph and the server that I wanted to join is not using any LAN and have a really good connection as the others can join it too without any problems that I've faced

Answer (score -1):

Ok, If you are on laptop, Are you playing on a Private world, or public server? if you are playing on a public server, then a Moderator/Administrator could be kicking you out of it or you might have been banned from that server. If your on a private world, How big is the world? I am asking this because if it is super big with millions of blocks built up from the ground, it could be killswitching (Lagging then kicking) you off your world.

Comment: I've play on private/ whitelist server which is built by my partner using MineOS. In fact, I don't know how large the world is but we already explored approximately 5O thousands blocks away from the spawn located. When I'm log in into the server the terrain load faster and placidly well. But after a couple of minutes, I'm start to having a lag issues due to the line although my ping is really low about 6-10ms. Next, when I'm having the issues I've been kicked out with " Connection Lost ", " Connection Timed Out ", ETC... Although I don't have any lines issues here.

Comment: Besides, when I click refresh on the server list, the first thing came out for the private server status is " Can't Connect to the Server ". During that time, the other server can be connected and doesn't have any issues but for this private server, it's like oddly having a issues. I've tried to contact the other players who play on this Private SMP too, and they said that they could join the server smoothly without a problems or any kicked out due to " Connection Lost ", ETC

Comment: One more, I'm using a mobile hotspot and same with the rest player like 2 people who've using the identical technique as mine due to we can't afford the modem/router since we're in College Debt. I've already tried any technique that could help me, for the hotspots I tried to use other APN, upgraded the internet and contacting the carrier server. When I contact the carrier service, they said that my area doesn't have any problems and they already come to my dorm to check what's the difficulty and they still said: " it's not because of the line but who knows? ".

Comment: Ok so your connection must not be secure enough. I have had that problem on pocket edition (I know it isnt the same) where i try to connect to a local server, and i found out that either my WIFI wasnt working, or there was a tower out in that area. I would try and contact your local HotSpot Provider and ask them if there was any reported tower outages. If there was, Then the tower could shut off due to people working on it.