# Minecraft Can't join LAN Worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been having this error for about 2 years now:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectionException: Connection timed out: no further information
```

[image]

It started a long time ago when I was messing with my network or firewall settings.

I have even reinstalled Windows. I'm able to join on servers, but not any LAN worlds.

I am on 1.17.1, but this error has been happening since 1.16.2 or somewhere around that version.
I have searched a few of the similar questions and those didn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: Also see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co