# My friend can connect to my minecraft java server, but I can't

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting, networking

Background:
I have started a Minecraft server on my old laptop and leave it on in the back of my office. I have been able to connect to it while on the same network from my main laptop  using the old laptops' ip address on my local network. My friend has been able to connect from his laptop to the old laptops' public ip address from his house.

The problem is, from my main laptop on a different network I am unable to use my old laptops' public ip address to connect to my server. It seems that my main laptop does not see the server, as I get a "connection timed out" error when attempting to connect.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the connection time out when connecting to a server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/why-does-the-connection-time-out-when-connecting-to-a-server)

Comment: The network you're trying to connect from might block port 25565. You can check by trying to connect to other Minecraft servers. If you can't connect to other servers, change your server port to one not blocked by the network and try again.